# How to position the labels of the path in automata?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

This is my tikz code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=7 cm,
                semithick, scale = 0.6, transform shape]


\node[initial,state] (A)                                    {$s_0$};
\node[state]         (B) [above right of=A]                 {$s_1$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=A]                 {$s_2$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=B]                         {$s_3$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D]                 {$s_4$};
\node[state]         (F) [below right of=D]                 {$s_5$};


  \path (A) edge [left]             node {$0$ $ \rightarrow $ [$x$ = $x.0.0$] } (B)
        edge [left]             node {$1$ $ \rightarrow $ [$x$ = $x.0.1$] } (C)
(B) edge [loop above]       node {$0$ $ \rightarrow\\ $  [$x$ = $x.0$] }   (B)
        edge [bend right,left]  node {$1$ $ \rightarrow $ [$x$ = $x.1$] }   (C)
    edge []                 node {$\$$ $ \rightarrow $ [$x$ = $x.0.\$$] } (D);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am getting this :

[image]

My doubts are :

1. Right now all labels are exactly at center of any arrow. How to change its position?
2. I gave `\\` within the label description. Still it didn't show in new line.  For example,
   `(B) edge [loop above]       node {$0$ $ \rightarrow\\$  [$x$ = $x.0$] }   (B)`. I have given `\\` after `\rightarrow` (ie  `$ \rightarrow\\$`). Still everything coming in the same line. How to give a line break there?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. To change the position of the labels use `pos=0.25`to specify the position along the path.
2. To use a `\\` , you need to specify the alignment of the text, so something like `align=center` (or you can specify the `text width`).

You should also reconsider how you are using `$` to enter and exit math mode.  So something like `$\$$ $ \rightarrow $ [$x$ = $x.0.\$$]` should really be specified as:

```
$\$  \rightarrow  [x = x.0.\$]$
```

and if you want to use a `\\` , then it should be:

```
$\$  \rightarrow$ \\  $[x = x.0.\$]$
```

You can also use `sloped` to get the text to go along the line.  The colors below have been used to more easily see how the code below relates to the image:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=7 cm,
                semithick, scale = 0.4, transform shape]


\node[initial,state] (A)                    {$s_0$};
\node[state]         (B) [above right of=A] {$s_1$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=A] {$s_2$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=B] {$s_3$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D] {$s_4$};
\node[state]         (F) [below right of=D] {$s_5$};


  \path (A) 
    edge [left] node [blue, pos=0.5, sloped, above] {$0 \rightarrow [x = x.0.0]$} (B)
    edge [left] node [cyan, pos=0.8]{$1 \rightarrow [x = x.0.1]$} (C)(B) 
    edge [loop above] node [align=center] {$0 \rightarrow$ \\ $[x = x.0]$ }   (B)
    edge [bend right,left] node  {$1 \rightarrow [x = x.1]$ }   (C)
    edge [] node [red, pos=0.2] {$\$  \rightarrow  [x = x.0.\$]$ } (D);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```