# Tikz edge label position

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs

Is there a way to set the location of the position of edge label when using the tikz graph package?

I attempted to look for samples of this being done in the manual, but was unable to find any (closest I got was in 19.6 where it shows how to set some options for individual edges).

Is this possible?

**Edit:** more specifically, I am looking for a way to put the label above or below the edge.

**Edit to add MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,positioning,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered, trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}
     {1->[edge label=hello]2};
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you seen [Moving a label along the path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29712) or [How to position the labels of the path in automata?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57958) ?

Comment: @cmhughes This is using the graph library which has a different syntax.

Comment: I suppose he thought that was what you meant by 'graph package'. Do you mean `tkz-graph`? (Which is not TikZ, but a package built on TikZ.)  Edit: Could you create a minimal example perhaps?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. no, I mean the `graphs` library, (used with `\begin{graph}...\end{graph}` in a tikzpicture environment).

Comment: A minimal example would have made this clearer. I haven't installed PGF 3.0 yet, so I can't really help I'm afraid, but there's probably someone else who can.

Comment: Just came across this one again. I think the labels are placed with the `auto` option enabled, placing the label above the line for your example. To place it below, add `swap`, i.e. `{1->[edge label=hello,swap]2};` Does that answer your question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry I missed this somehow. If you add it as an answer it will be accepted.

Comment: @soandos Ok, done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The labels seem to be placed with the `auto` option enabled, which places the node/label on the side of the line, in your MWE above it. As such you can add the `swap` option to move the label to the other side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,positioning,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered, trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}
     {1 -> [edge label=hello]
      2 -> [edge label=hello,swap]
      3};
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```