# Label on an arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, arrows, labels, bezier

This question is a follow-up for my badly accepted

[Bézier curves for arrows in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550735/b%c3%a9zier-curves-for-arrows-in-tikz)

I have come up with the following. The Bézier-curve arrow works, but my label doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[state/.style={rectangle,draw=black, rounded corners},arrow/.style={->,semithick}]

\node[state] (theory) at (0,4) {theory};
\node[state] (chain) at (4,-2) {chain};
\node[state] (prove) at (0,0) {prove};
\node[state] (state) at (8,0) {state};
\draw [arrow] (state) .. controls (8,-2) and (6,-2) .. (chain) {then};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

TeXWorks on Windows 10 complains about

```
! Use of \pgfutil@next doesn't match its definition.
l.16 ... controls (8,-2) and (6,-2) .. (chain) {th
                                                  en};
?
```

How can I create a label for this arrow?

Comment: Where do you want to put the label? At the midway from `(state)` to `(chain)`, or around the `(chain)`? Also, `edge` is recommended to draw arrows like this, see the complete step-by-step example in [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 3.

Comment: I would like to put it on the curve, not at the tip of the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
\draw [arrow] (state) .. controls (8,-2) and (6,-2) ..   (chain) node [midway, below] {then} ;
```

works: I have found the necessary ingredients at

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170716/27523

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `edge`:

```
\draw[arrow] (state) edge[out=-90, in=0, looseness=1.1] node[auto] {then} (chain);
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[state/.style={rectangle,draw=black, rounded corners},arrow/.style={->,semithick}]
  \node[state] (theory) at (0,4) {theory};
  \node[state] (chain) at (4,-2) {chain};
  \node[state] (prove) at (0,0) {prove};
  \node[state] (state) at (8,0) {state};
  \draw[arrow] (state) edge[out=-90, in=0, looseness=1.1] node[auto] {then} (chain);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compared to the curved path construction (`edge` draws in blue):
[image]